# Further Generalization of Jordan Curve Theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology

Recently I have read the proof of the Jordan Curve Theorem in Munkres' Topology, I wonder whether there are some generalizations and corollaries on this theorem as follows:

1. I know any simple closed curve separate $\mathbb R^2$ into two components, one is bounded and the other one is unbounded. How to prove that the bounded component is simply connected and the unbounded component is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2-\{0\}$?
2. Can the theorem be generalized into higher dimension? Given a simple closed curve in $\mathbb R^n$, does there exist $U\in\mathbb R^n$ such that $U$ is a simply connected 2-manifold whose boundary is exactly the curve?

I believe the first question would be a simple consequence of Jordan Curve Theorem (although I cannot figure out a proof, can any one give me one if possible?). However I am not quite sure whether my second question is even related to the JCT.

Comment: For #1, you want the Jordan–Schoenflies theorem.

Comment: Some references related to the question are given in this paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1404.0556 which also applies the algebra of groupoids rather than covering spaces as in Munkres' proof. Wilder's 1949 volume on "Topology of Manifolds" has lots of related results.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to 2 as stated is no. Any open set $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ will have to be an n-manifold. (This is not hard to prove at all). So the correct generalization will be with $n-1$ manifolds instead of curves. This is known as the [Jordan Separation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem#Proof_and_generalizations). However, the interior need not be homeomorphic to a sphere in higher dimensions. Check out the [Alexander Horned Sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_horned_sphere), which is a counter example when $n=3$.

Comment: I have heard a theorem, it is stated that if $F$ is a vector field in $\mathbb R^3$ and $curl(F)=0$, then the work done along any simple closed curve is zero. The proof is that any simple closed curve in $\mathbb R^3$ can be written as a boundary of a simply connected surface, and the result follows from Stroke's theorem. Then is #2 correct in the case of $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: For the Alexander Sphere, one of the component is not simply connected while another one is. Is my statement true if I need only one component simply connected?

Comment: A surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ will not be an open subset. I do believe that any smooth simple closed curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is the boundary of some smooth surface.

Comment: My mistakes, I forgot that a surface in $\mathbb R^3$ is not open. Let me remove this condition.

Answer (score 3):

The entirety of [knot theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot_theory) is founded on the premise that the answer to your second question, in the case of $\mathbb{R}^3$, is "no". The first counterexample usually encountered is the [trefoil knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot_theory#/media/File:TrefoilKnot_01.svg).